# Integrating a XMPP server into existing Rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

We are running a ruby on rails web application(database: mysql) with iphone/android client, with existing users & data. In the upcoming release, we want to add a **chat** feature, and one solution is: use XMPP.

However, giving that there are so many choice for XMPP servers. And, it might be very difficult for small teams like us to modify/debug/maintain the source of big open source projects.

**So what's your recommandations for *easy-to-integrate-xmpp-servers*?**

Things we need to integrate with XMPP server, (including but not limited, cause we'll have more features in the future)
1. all our users properties (names, emails) and their relationships
2. get callback from XMPP server when a user send a message to an offline friend (cause we need push notification to iphone)
3. query user's status in XMPP server

We are ready to modify their code, but as less as possible.

ejabberd? openfire? tigase? prosody? Which is the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for ejabberd, but I am biased because I know it very well.
However, we are using a lot Rails at ProcessOne as well, and ejabberd will act as a blackbox mostly.
You should not have any trouble with it.

Keep us informed of your progress :)

Answer (score 0):

the alternate is Openfire which is a real time collaboration (RTC) server licensed under the Open Source Apache License.